# DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer using any of the configured protocols

Tags: c#, dcom, clsid

I am currently on a problem, here is the situation :

The aim is to use a dll from serverA to write in a database on serverB (it's not SQL database it's RAIMA database).

A webservice on a serverB runs the following script :

```cs
oClassType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Wonderware.MaterialSrv.wwMaterialDB.1", serverA);
oMaterialDB = (Wonderware.InBatch.MaterialServer.IMaterialDB)Activator.CreateInstance(oClassType);
```

on the second line the script throw the exception :

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {03BD256F-6114-11D1-9E81-00A0C939AC09} from machine serverA failed due to the following error: 800706ba serverA

I have set the right DCOM access (the WS account has the right access normally) on the .exe which is used but his CLSID is {03BD2562-6114-11D1-9E81-00A0C939AC09}.
The firewall is off.

And from serverA in the event viewer I got :

> DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer ჸ൵蠀 using any of the configured protocols; 
>      requested by PID        0 ().

Like the servername is writtren with chinese symbols and the PID is 0 !

From serverB I have this in event viewer :

> DCOM got error "2147746132" from the computer serverA when attempting to activate the server: {03BD256F-6114-11D1-9E81-00A0C939AC09}

This one makes sense... I guess the problem is on serverA.

Anyone has any idea what can possibly goes wrong ?